# Hash ripemd160 on Android?

Tags: android, hash

On Android, are available libraries for generate [ripemd160](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIPEMD#RIPEMD-160_hashes) hashes?

Comment: Uhm, why "-1" ?

Comment: Probably because you can easily check supported algorithms in the docs.
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/MessageDigest

Comment: Well, I didi it, but ripemd160 is not listed. Probably we should use something from `org.bouncycastle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/MessageDigest), it looks like the ripemd160 hash algorithm is not included among the standard hashes. Anyway we can import **[Spongy Castle](https://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/)**, which includes an implementation in the class **[org.spongycastle.crypto.digests.RIPEMD160Digest](https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle/blob/spongy-master/core/src/main/java/org/spongycastle/crypto/digests/RIPEMD160Digest.java)**.